# Insert from One Table Into Another with Where clause

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert values from table 2 (in the pacp2 column) into table 1 (in the pacp column) where the facility_id from both tables matches and where table1 pacp column is null.  I get the following error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 The multi-part identifier
>   "table1.FACILITYID" could not be bound. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 5 The multi-part identifier "table1.pacp" could not be bound.

Does anyone know why this isn't working?  I've tried using alias for both tables but that won't work.

```
INSERT INTO database.dbo.table1 (pacp)
SELECT pacp2
FROM table2 
WHERE database.dbo.table1.facility_id = database.dbo.table2.facility_id 
    AND database.dbo.table1.pacp IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The description of your question suggests that you are looking for an `update` rather than an `insert`.

Here is one option using an updatable cte:

```
with cte as (
    select t1.pacp, t2.pacp2
    from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2 on t1.facility_id = t2.facility_id 
    where t1.pacp is null
)
update cte set pacp = pacp2
```

For rows of `table1` where `pacp` is `null`, the query attempts to retrieve the value of `pacp2` from `table2`, using `facility_id` for matching. If it succeeds, then it updates the corresponding row in `table1` and sets `pacp` to the value of `pacp2`.